# Reference member variables as class members in Swift

Tags: ios, class, reference, swift

I want to create a class with a member working as a reference or a pointer.

Here is my code

```
class A {
    var arr = [Int]()

    func fill() {
        arr += 2
    }
}

class B {
    var arr = [Int]()

    func fill() {
        arr += 3
    }
}


var arr = [1]

var a = A()
a.arr = arr
a.fill()

var b = B()
b.arr = arr
b.fill()

println("\(arr) -- \(a.arr) -- \(b.arr)")
```

The output is `[1] -- [1, 2] -- [1, 3]` and I want to get `[1, 2, 3] -- [1, 2, 3] -- [1, 2, 3]`

I have tried to add a setter with an `inout` parameter to my classes but I get the same result...

Comment: Your code is correct. I don't know why your console output is [1] -- [1, 2] -- [1, 3]. The correct display must be: [1, 2, 3] -- [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] -- [1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9]. But not [1, 2, 3] -- [1, 2, 3] -- [1, 2, 3] cause the attribute 'arr' of your instances a and b are modified.

Comment: Oups ! I've changed my code for more lisibility but I have forgotten to update my question... I've updated my post. Sorry for the fail.

Comment: You want to update original 'arr', isn't it?

Comment: I want the three `arr` to be the same. When I update `A.arr` I want to retrieve this update in `arr` and `B.arr`.

Comment: In swift, only class object is passed by reference. Try to create a class that hold .arr then update this instance in your A & B.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class A {
    var myC : C?;

    func fill(inout a:[Int]) {
        a += 2
    }

    func updateC(c : C) {
        fill(&c.arr)
        myC = c;
    }
}

class B {
    var myC : C?;

    func fill(inout a:[Int]) {
        a += 3
    }

    func updateC(c : C) {
        fill(&c.arr)
        myC = c;
    }
}


class C {
    var arr = [Int]()

}
```

and in another class:

```
var c = C()
c.arr = [1]

var a = A()
a.updateC(c)

var b = B()
b.updateC(c)

println("\(c.arr) -- \(a.myC!.arr) -- \(b.myC!.arr)")
```

It should print the same values.

Comment: It work but it's not really "sexy"... Anyway, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Swift Arrays are pass by value so they don't really work that way without some finagling. You could also try using NSMutableArray, which you can pass by reference, but that has its own drawbacks such as only holding AnyObjects.

```
class A {
    var arr = NSMutableArray()

    func fill() {
        arr.addObject(2)
    }
}

class B {
    var arr = NSMutableArray()

    func fill() {
        arr.addObject(3)
    }
}

var arr: NSMutableArray = [1]

var a = A()
a.arr = arr
a.fill()

var b = B()
b.arr = arr
b.fill()

println("\(arr) -- \(a.arr) -- \(b.arr)")
```